# How to know from which JS function a local storage is generating

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I need to know from which part of JavaScript code is generating a local storage when a page is loading. How can I debug this in Chrome debugger? or is there any way? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's an object so you could just do `console.log(localStorage)` and check with dev tools what it contains.

Comment: Thanks for reply Shikk...I tried tht and getting an object with list of storage but i need to knw from where its generating

Comment: Could be from within *any* script, no way to tell like this...

Comment: @Bryce77 do you have the code ?

Comment: i have but cant share due to non disclosure. On page load a local storage is generating. I need to find frm where its coming...its huge code..